# Clustering Evaluation

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

Lets say I have a  labeled dataset to be clustered (label is to identify each data to which cluster it belongs too). Now if I used any clustering algorithm in Matlab (kmeans,...) how could I know if an instance is clustered correctly or not. 
Knowing that lets say kmeans clustered instance one of the dataset to be in clusters 2 but the labeled data says that it belongs to cluster 1. However, cluster 2 in the labeled dataset could be the same as cluster one in the predicted labels (but have different **reversed** names in both predicted and Labeled). What do you suggest?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you're trying to compare the "ground truth" labels with the one your algorithm found, and have the problem that they might be grouped correctly, but with different labels. If that's right, you could try [grp2idx](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/grp2idx.html) on both label vectors, as that seems to assign the first cluster it finds label "1" and the next "2" and so on.

Edit: grp2idx does not do that, it just changes the labels to the smallest possible ones, but grp2idx([ 2 1 2 2 3 ]) becomes [ 2 1 2 2 3 ], so it does not order them differently. You could for example take the output of grp2idx on both label vectors, substract them, and for each unique value of the label vector the difference should be the same.

Comment: this is a good approach, i can use the XOR function to do similar things, yet  I would not know if the labels i got refers to the true labels or not in case the name of the clusters are reversed.

Comment: could you please update your question with a small example? I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "reversed"

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia discusses several approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#External_evaluation).

> A number of measures are adapted from variants used to evaluate classification tasks. In place of counting the number of times a class was correctly assigned to a single data point (known as true positives), such pair counting metrics assess whether each pair of data points that is truly in the same cluster is predicted to be in the same cluster.

Pair counting metrics solve the problem of having to match clusters to classes, by looking on an agreement what is "same" and what is "different".

Comment: YES, I already know that, but these measures assume that I know which instances are clustered correctly and which are not

Comment: No, they don't. They assume you have labels and clusters, that's all. They have their own concept of "correctly", based on pairs. They do *not* require you to know label A = cluster 1, but they are designed in a way that this does not matter.